# Brand new to Cassandra, having trouble understanding replication topology

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, nodes, datastax

So I'm taking over our Cassandra cluster after the previous admin left so I'm busy trying to learn as much as I can about it.  I'm going through all the documentation on Datastax's site as we're using their product.

That said, on the replication factor part I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why I wouldn't have the replication factor set to the number of nodes I have.  I have four nodes currently and one datacenter, all nodes are located in the same physical location as well.

What, if any, benefit would there be to having a replication factor of less than 4?

I'm just thinking that it would be beneficial from a fault tolerance standpoint if each node had its own copy/replica of the data, not sure why I would want less replicas than the number of nodes I have.  Are there performance tradeoffs or other reasons?  Am I COMPLETELY missing the concept here (entirely possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why you might not want to increase your RF from 3 to 4:

1. Increasing your RF effectively multiplies your original data volume
   by that amount. Depending on your data volume and data density you
   may not want to incur the additional storage hit. RF > number of nodes will help you scale beyond one node's capacity.
2. Depending on your consistency level you could experience a performance hit. I.E. when writing with quorum consistency level (CL) to an RF of 3 you wait for 2 nodes to come back before confirming the write to the client. In RF of 4 you would be waiting for 3 nodes to come back.
3. Regardless of the CL, every write will eventually be going to every node. This is more activity on your cluster and may not perform well if your nodes aren't scaled for that workload.

You mentioned fault tolerance. With an RF of 4 and reads on CL one, you can absorb up to 3 of your servers being down simultaneously and your app will still be up. From a fault tolerance perspective this is pretty impressive, but also unlikely. My guess would be if you have 3 nodes down at the same time in the same dc, the 4th is probably also down (natural disaster, flood, who knows...).

At the end of the day it all depends on your needs and C* is nothing if not configurable. An RF of 3 is very common among Cassandra implementations

#### [Check out this deck by Joe Chu](http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/201404-cluster-sizing)

Comment: Ok thanks for the replies, I now have a MUCH greater understanding of RF.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your RF is often less than the number of nodes in the cluster is explained in the post: [Cassandra column family bigger than nodes drive space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897406/cassandra-column-family-bigger-than-nodes-drive-space/15897748#15897748). This post provides insight into this interesting aspect of Cassandra replication. Here's a summary of the post:

> QUESTION: . .. every node has 2Tb drive space and column family is replicated on every node so every node contains a full copy of it . . . after some years that column family will exceed 2Tb . . .
>
> Answer: RF can be less than the number of nodes and does not need to scale if you add more nodes.
>
> For example, if you today had 3 nodes with RF 3, each node will
>   contain a copy of all the data, as you say. But then if you add 3 more
>   nodes and keep RF at 3, each node will have half the data. You can
>   keep adding more nodes so each node contains a smaller and smaller
>   proportion of the data . . . no limit in principle to
>   how big your data can be.